Cambiar el icono de mi aplicación en flutter
Tengo este código en mi pubspect.yaml para modificar el icono de mi aplicación, pero no funciona, ¿no puedo cambiar el icono de mi aplicación al revisar me di cuenta de que si se crearon las imágenes necesarias, pero cuando compilo la aplicación esta sale sin logo, que es lo que estoy haciendo mal?
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.8
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.7.0
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.14.1
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.9.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^4.0.0

flutter_icons:
  android: true
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/Logo.png"

Y este es mi AndroidManifest.xml
<application
        android:label="Riotuor"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">


Veo que estas usando el paquete flutter_launcher_icons la version 0.14.1.
en el archivo pubspec.yaml tienes nueve la declaración del paquete de dependencies a dev_dependencies.
Luego reemplazar flutter_icons: por:
flutter_launcher_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/icon/icon.png"
  min_sdk_android: 21 # android min sdk min:16, default 21

y finalmente ejecutas en el terminal:
flutter pub get
dart run flutter_launcher_icons

puede leer su documentación en https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons
